# php script ends without any error

Tags: php, .htaccess, crash

I have a php script that reads a `csv` file that contains URLs, follows the URLs, parses them and save some data into a database. The `csv` is around 1000 lines. However, my php script seems to stop after parsing some URLs (between 2 and 15 - never less, never more, but always different) neither showing any error in the browser nor writing it to `php_errors.php`.

I have also placed enabled php server logging via .htaccess:

```
# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log "home/user/public_html/path/php_errors.log"
```

Also did I set the logging parameters in the php script with:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I have no idea how to catch the reason why the script breaks. It really works perfect until it stops.

Before adding this question I run into another question on stackoverflow and addressed all the resolutions.
I set `display_errors = on` in php.ini.
My script has no syntax errors and it parses well to a point.

Comment: Mind sharing your PHP script that parses the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

[How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

you can also check the /var/log/apache/ folder and try to locate error.log - it should contain error message independent of error show settings

Comment: It's not working. I asked the administrator to get the var/log/apache/error.log - hopefully it will contain something.

Comment: The admin just told me that the error logs are empty! Have any other idea?

Comment: if there is nothing in logs, your script is not ending with a error. Check logic in your script, there need to be something that causes script to be finished

Comment: It cannot be! Some times ends after 2 records, some times ends after 15 records. There's no pattern, though, and I'm running the same script...